# Is Sher-Wood T90 considered a pro stock hockey stick?

Tags: equipment, ice-hockey

Is Sher-Wood T90 considered a pro stock hockey stick? Do some NHL players use it?

Comment: Please look at answer provided if that's not what you intended to know, comment and suggest clarification.

Comment: PSA: this question is being discussed on [meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/is-this-question-considered-as-localized/).

Comment: I guess I wanted to find out if any professional hockey players have used this stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentioned Sher-Wood T90 hockey stick, doesn't appear to be pro stock hockey but is retail version (followed the link of the picture to [prohockeylife.com](https://www.prohockeylife.com/composite-hockey-sticks/senior-sticks/sher-wood-true-touch-t90-gen-ii-grip-sr-hockey-stick-p-12444)).

ProStockHockey website shows a [difference between pro stock and retail version](https://www.prostockhockey.com/pro-stock-vs-retail/), and there is a [pro version of Sher-Wood T90 hockey stick](https://www.prostockhockey.com/clearance-sticks/right-steve-bernier-t90-95-flex-stick/) branded under New York Islanders player [Steve Bernier](https://www.nhl.com/player/steve-bernier-8470609).

[image: t90 pro] 
[image: back]